# Any risks of reading arbitrary emails in HTML format?

Tags: virus, risk

Emails can be sent with email software (via corresponding setting of a parameter in the software) in HTML format instead of the normal text format. Are there any risks of reading arbitrary (malicious) emails in HTML format?

Comment: Spammers can track your email activity using img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends; it is possible to include malicious code (e.g. JavaScript) in HTML e-mails, but all serious e-mail applications (be it web apps or desktop apps) will prevent this from running when you read it, and exclude them if you decide to save the e-mail as HTML. Good PDF readers will do the same with 'infected' PDFs, actually.

If you somehow intercept the raw e-mail body, save it as a HTML file, and open it in a browser, you run the same risks as opening a random link on the Internet.